# Sql query find the car whcih is having maximim mileage

Tags: mysql, count, sum, sql-order-by, sql-limit

find the car  whcih is having maximum mileage

```
id,car,timestamp,mileage
101,audi,10/10/10 9:05:02,10.5
101,audi,10/10/10 9:07:02,10
101,audi,10/10/10 9:14:02,9
102,benz,10/10/10 8:24:02,8
102,benz,10/10/10 8:34:02,7
102,benz,10/10/10 8:44:02,6
```

Expected Out

```
audi =(10.5+10+9)/3 = 9.83
benz=(8+7+6)/3= 7
```

Comment: (1) What is your expected result? (2) What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for aggregation:

```
select 
    car,
    sum(mileage) / count(*) res
from mytable
group by id, car
```

If you want to retain only the car with the greatest result, then you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select 
    car,
    sum(mileage) / count(*) res
from mytable
group by id, car
order by res desc
limit 1
```